# How to construct an OpenSea order hash in Java?

Tags: opensea, java

my code to construct an default order hash as follow:
public class BuildTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    StructuredDataEncoder dataEncoder = new StructuredDataEncoder(parse().toJSONString());
    HashMap<String, Object> o1Map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    o1Map.put("offerer", "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
    o1Map.put("zone", "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
    List<Map<String, Object>> offerMapList = new ArrayList<>();
    o1Map.put("offer", offerMapList);

    List<Map<String, Object>> considerationMapList = new ArrayList<>();
    o1Map.put("consideration", considerationMapList);
    o1Map.put("orderType",0);
    o1Map.put("startTime", 0);
    o1Map.put("endTime",0);
    o1Map.put("zoneHash", "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
    o1Map.put("salt", 0);
    o1Map.put("conduitKey", "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
    o1Map.put("counter", 0);
    
    byte[] dataHash = dataEncoder.encodeData("OrderComponents",o1Map);
    System.out.println(Numeric.toHexString(Hash.sha3(dataHash)));
}

private static JSONObject parse(){
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("domain",JSONObject.parseObject("{\"chainId\":5,\"name\":\"Seaport\",\"verifyingContract\":\"0x00000000000000ADc04C56Bf30aC9d3c0aAF14dC\",\"version\":\"1.5\"}"));
    jsonObject.put("primaryType","OrderComponents");
    jsonObject.put("message",new Object());
    jsonObject.put("types",JSONObject.parseObject("{\"EIP712Domain\":[{\"name\":\"name\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"version\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"chainId\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"name\":\"verifyingContract\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"OfferItem\":[{\"name\":\"itemType\",\"type\":\"uint8\"},{\"name\":\"token\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"name\":\"identifierOrCriteria\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"name\":\"startAmount\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"name\":\"endAmount\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"ConsiderationItem\":[{\"name\":\"itemType\",\"type\":\"uint8\"},{\"name\":\"token\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"name\":\"identifierOrCriteria\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"name\":\"startAmount\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"name\":\"endAmount\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"name\":\"recipient\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"OrderComponents\":[{\"name\":\"offerer\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"name\":\"zone\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"name\":\"offer\",\"type\":\"OfferItem[]\"},{\"name\":\"consideration\",\"type\":\"ConsiderationItem[]\"},{\"name\":\"orderType\",\"type\":\"uint8\"},{\"name\":\"startTime\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"name\":\"endTime\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"name\":\"zoneHash\",\"type\":\"bytes32\"},{\"name\":\"salt\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"name\":\"conduitKey\",\"type\":\"bytes32\"},{\"name\":\"counter\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}]}"));
    return jsonObject;
}

public static byte[] keccak256(byte[] data) {
    KeccakDigest digest = new KeccakDigest(256);
    digest.update(data, 0, data.length);
    byte[] result = new byte[digest.getDigestSize()];
    digest.doFinal(result, 0);
    return result;
}
```

i get order hash :0xbd24952f20d4ca67dda20ad09cb1e045b121c297525050e060a17216f2a6e817
but expect:0x06bfdd4fee487c47799fd9aa57225e03268298d2983ff74cbab178665fab33ea
how can i get the right order hash??

Answer (score 0):

```
        byte[] dataHash = dataEncoder.hashMessage(
                dataEncoder.jsonMessageObject.getPrimaryType(),
                (HashMap<String, Object>) dataEncoder.jsonMessageObject.getMessage());
        String dataHashString = Numeric.toHexString(dataHash);
        System.out.println("orderHash: " + dataHashString);
```

Comment: i try, but i can't  get the right order hash

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with your input, I'm sure this is how the orderhash is calculated.

Comment: The version of the org.web3j.crypto jar package I am using is 4.10.1. what's your version?